# Precompiling bits/stdc++.h went unsuccessfull

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, precompiled-headers

I was compiling **bits/stdc++.h header** included with **mingw-w64** in using

```
g++ -std=c++17 stdc++.h
```

I got a list of errors ending with

C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:167:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_string_view<wchar_t>' to 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&&'

C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:165:5: note: candidate: 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::path(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&)'
path(const path& __p) = default;
^~~~

C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:165:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_string_view<wchar_t>' to 'const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&'

C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:163:5: note: candidate: 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::path()'
path() noexcept { }
^~~~

C:/MinGW/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:163:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

but on compiling with

```
g++ -std=c++14 stdc++.h
```

**it get's precompiled**

Is there any way to **precompile it with c++17** ?

Comment: Why do you want to precompile some non-standard header?

Comment: Yes but It is included with mingw-w64. It is used in competitive programming etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "included"? An end user is not supposed to use headers that are internal to a standard library implementation.

Comment: @Evg GCC manual advises you do exactly this. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_headers.html

Comment: Generally: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) As long as you don't `#include` it yourself it's fine.

Comment: And so-called "competitive programming" sites are ***not*** any kind of learning or teaching resource. Using them as such could instead be actively harmful for your learning. Their examples are usually bad and often invalid as well. Learn programming and a few languages *first*, before ever looking at such sites.

Comment: @Amish GCC 8 is a bit outdated. I wouldn't be surprised if the `<filesystem>` header was broken in it. I've just tried `g++ -std=c++17 stdc++.h` on GCC 11 from MSYS2, and it worked correctly.

Comment: Precompiling it with c++17 in MinGW is working but in mingw-w64 it is generating errors?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat so I should use MSYS2 then ?

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend using MSYS2 regardless of precompiled headers.

Comment: Is there any benefit of precompiling headers ?

Comment: Competitive coding sites do train your problem solving skills but they also teach horrible coding styles (really!).  If you want to learn C++, learn that first.  If you can't get your hands om some recent C++ books (at least covering C++11 in detail preferable newer) then you can start learning more on C++ here : https://www.learncpp.com/. Right after that a good read is  : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: Precompiled headers can speed up compilation speeds, they're like a cache so that the compiler doesn't have to reparse them on the next compile (provided the header files didn't change)

Comment: *"Is there any benefit of precompiling headers?"* If you don't know that, why are you trying to do it? :) Yes, they're supposed to improve build times.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah I was just confirming it Thanks :)

Comment: But for competitive programming site type code -- they would be practically worthless. Instead of picking up  bad habits trying to learn from those sites, stop by [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3422102) and learn C++, then go exercise your problem solving skills.

Comment: I am very against the header `bits/stdc++.h` for "competitive programming" or other uses. But `stdc++.h` is *designed* to be used as precompiled header, so this question makes sense, provided you only build with GCC.